# Open Microsoft Access file using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to open Microsoft Access 2003 file using C#.

I need working complete code which I can put in my .cs file which I then compile using csc.exe and the target:winexe setting to produce my exe which I can then double click and it opens my Access file.

The Access file will be in the same directory as the c# exe I will need the Access file path to be relative path so which ever directory I place them in it works.

I have tried the code below and google this for days and tried countless other codes but none work for me.

```
Access.Application oAccess = null;

// Start a new instance of Access for Automation:
oAccess = new Access.ApplicationClass();

// Open a database in exclusive mode:
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(
   "c:\\mydb.mdb", //filepath
   true //Exclusive
   );
```

Comment: You want to create a C# application that when double-clicked will simply launch Access and open a database file? If so, then why not just double-click the database file itself and let Windows launch Access for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want Process.Start("example.txt");

[See full details here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/process)

Comment: Hi osahon That link shows no information form. Can you post working sample code for me?

Comment: Process.Start(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\Access2010DB\AgeRange.mdb")

Comment: I put Process.Start(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\Access2010DB\AgeRang‌​e.mdb") with my filepath in my .cs file but it doesn't compile?

Comment: Tried the following in my .cs file bur again doesn't compile can anyone help with working sample?  access = new Access.ApplicationClass();
access.Visible = false; //open access in the background
access.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"db1.mdb", false, null);

Comment: Hi osahon  The error code is   cs0116 something to do with namespace But I really think I should be using the OpenCurrentDatabase code like what i posted above if you know how to make it work i think it would solve problem. im not running c# command line im running c# windows exe no buttons no forms just execute the code and open the Access file.

Comment: I used System.Diagnostics.Process.  Add Using System.Diagnostics; to your code.